# Dropdown pages in Settings API

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, settings-api

I am working with theme option. There is dropdown option like this.

```
        'memory' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'label' => __('Memory', 'fw'),
                'choices' => array(
                    'fa fa-facebook' => __('Facebook', 'fw'),
                    'fa fa-twitter' => __('Twitter', 'fw'),
                    'fa fa-gplus' => __('G-Plus', 'fw'),
                )
            ),
```

To make choice as page dropdown. I am pretty closer I think. I modified:

```
        'memory' => array(
                'type'  => 'select',
                'label' => __('Memory', 'fw'),
                'choices' => get_pages( array(
                ) ),
            ),
```

But this gave only select items not the page id. The output:

```
<select>
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="2"></option>
</select>
```

What are the other edits for this?

Comment: That is not the wordpress settings API.

Comment: Are you sure about this!!!!!! What makes you think this is not settings api?

Comment: if it doesn't look like a duck and do not make quack noises then most likely it is not a duck ;)